# How to improve this Algorithm?

Tags: r

R Version 2.11.1 32-bit on Windows 7

I get the data train.txt as below:

```
USER_A USER_B ACTION
1        7      0
1        8      1
2        6      2
2        7      1
3        8      2
```

And I deal with the data as the algorithm below:

```
train_data=read.table("train.txt",header=T)
result=matrix(0,length(unique(train_data$USER_B)),2)
result[,1]=unique(train_data$USER_B)
for(i in 1:dim(result)[1])
{
    temp=train_data[train_data$USER_B%in%result[i,1],]
    result[i,2]=sum(temp[,3])/dim(temp)[1]
}
```

the result is the score of every USER_B in train_data. the score is defined as:

score of USER_B=(the sum of all the ACTION of USER_B)/(the recommend times of USER_B)

but the train_data is very large, it may take me three days to finish this program, so I come here to ask for help, could this algorithm be improved?

Comment: My guess is that you should be able to avoid a for loop completely by vectorising your code.

Comment: Some pointers on your code. No need for `;` at the end of lines - R is *not* C! ;-) You don't need to initialise `i` the `for()` call does that for you, and likewise there is no need to increment `i` at the end of the loop. It is also better code to write `for(i in seq_len(nrow(result)))` rather than generating the sequence by hand, especially in production code.

Comment: By the way, how large is your dataset - try `nrow(train_data)`.  Be careful if it gets to be more than half of the available RAM.  If that happens, take a look at `bigmemory` and its related functions/packages: `bigsplit`, `mwhich`, and `bigtabulate`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running your example, your desired result is to calculate the mean ACTION for each unique USER_B:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7  0.5
[2,]    8  1.0
[3,]    6  2.0
```

You can do this with one line of code using the `ddply()` function in package `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
ddply(train_data[, -1], .(USER_B), numcolwise(mean))

  USER_B ACTION
1      6    2.0
2      7    0.5
3      8    1.0
```

Alternatively, the function `tapply` in base R does the same:

```
tapply(train_data$ACTION, train_data$USER_B, mean)
```

Depending on the size of your table, you can get an improvement in execution time of 20x or higher.  Here is the system.time test for a data.frame with a million entries.  Your algorithm takes 116 seconds, ddply() takes 5.4 seconds, and tapply takes 1.2 seconds:

```
train_data <- data.frame(
        USER_A = 1:1e6,
        USER_B = sample(1:1e3, size=1e6, replace=TRUE),
        ACTION = sample (1:100, size=1e6, replace=TRUE))

yourfunction <- function(){
    result <- matrix(0,length(unique(train_data$USER_B)),2)
    result[,1] <- unique(train_data$USER_B);
    for(i in 1:dim(result)[1]){     
        temp=train_data[train_data$USER_B%in%result[i,1],]
        result[i,2]=sum(temp[,3])/dim(temp)[1]
    }
    result
}

system.time(XX <- yourfunction())
   user  system elapsed 
 116.29   14.04  134.33 

system.time(YY <- ddply(train_data[, -1], .(USER_B), numcolwise(mean)))
   user  system elapsed 
   5.43    1.60    7.19 

system.time(ZZ <- tapply(train_data$ACTION, train_data$USER_B, mean))
   user  system elapsed 
   1.17    0.06    1.25
```

Comment: How about `system.time(VV <- rowsum(train_data$ACTION, train_data$USER_B)/rowsum(rep(1L,nrow(train_data)), train_data$USER_B))`?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the approaches provided by @Andrie, the `split()` then `lapply()` approach is faster still:

```
> system.time(ZZ <- tapply(train_data$ACTION, train_data$USER_B, mean))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.025   0.011   1.062 
> system.time(WW <- unlist(lapply(split(train_data$ACTION, 
+                                       f = train_data$USER_B), 
+                          mean)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.465   0.007   0.483
```

`sapply()` is also just as quick for this problem:

```
> system.time(SS <- sapply(split(train_data$ACTION, f = train_data$USER_B), 
+                          mean))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.469   0.001   0.474
```

Comment: also, perhaps worth noting that, if the data are truly huge, some speed-up might be achieved by replacing `mean` in the above with `function(x) sum(x) / length(x)`. I got about a 0.04 second speed-up over the solution shown in my answer, but if the loop really takes 3 days (!?), eking out a little extra efficiency might be useful?

Answer (score 4):

@gavin has already demonstrated the high performance when using a combination of `split` and `lapply`.

The package `data.table` offers a further noticeable performance increase of ~75%

```
library(data.table)
system.time({
      VV <- as.data.table(train_data)[, list(ACTION=mean(ACTION)), by=USER_B]
    })

user  system elapsed 
0.15    0.02    0.17 

system.time(WW <- unlist(lapply(split(train_data$ACTION, f = train_data$USER_B),mean)))

user  system elapsed 
0.61    0.02    0.63 

all(WW==VV$ACTION)
[1] TRUE
```

The `data.table` package is available at [CRAN](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html&rct=j&q=%5BR%5D%20data.table&ei=8mDCTenyF8-ahQfO_InIBQ&usg=AFQjCNFgrrG2Y8DKRNuvIA8wYuoiKR3y6g&cad=rja) and has website on [r-forge](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/)

Comment: Please see the [data.table wiki](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=packages:cran:data.table) for further improvements on that timing; e.g., use `.Internal(mean)`. Also, that 0.17 is timing the `as.data.table()`, too, which isn't required if it's a `data.table` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try at `tapply`:

```
train_data <- read.table("train.txt",header=T);
result <- tapply(train_data$ACTION,train_data$USER_B,function(x) sum(x)/length(x));
```

You can use `mean` instead of `function..`, but I have recently read that this last solution is faster (if you don't have any `NA`s etc.).

I have not tested but I believe this should be faster. If you want even a faster solution, have at look `Rcpp` and `inline` packages...

Comment: Even if you use `mean`, you can supply additional arguments (like `na.rm = TRUE` using `...`.